# Como Debugar o Laravel 5.2 no MAC utilizando o X-Debug?

Tags: laravel, xdebug

já tentei de tudo e até agora não consigo debugar o Laravel 5.2 no MAC alguma luz?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga, sem muitos detalhes. Comece lendo o guia de [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) e veja como pode melhorar sua pergunta.